# Why couldn’t Rabbi Yochanan revive Reish Lakish?

Tags: agada-stories-legends

We are told in Bava Kama 117b a story of how Rabbi Yochanan looked at Rav Kahana and killed him, and proceeded to then revive him.

We also know the story of how Rabbi Yochanan looked at Reish Lakish and killed him, and afterwards he was greatly distressed and missed his chavruta. So, if Rabbi Yochanan was able to revive the dead, why did he not revive, or at least attempt to revive, Reish Lakish?

Comment: לא בכל שעתא ושעתא מתרחיש ניסא

Comment: In the story of Rav Kahana, R’ Yochanon had made a mistake in thinking that he was laughing at him. In the story of Reish Lakish there was no mistake in the actual story, he just didn’t realize the severity of the loss until afterwards

Comment: @Chatzkel true I was thinking about that. In both stories each person disrespects Rabbi Yochanan in a way, but only in the Rav Kahana story was is unintentional. And then I guess the answer would be that Gd allowed Rav Kahana to be revived because he was “innocent” so to say, something not found by Reish Lakish. But still I’m wondering if anyone touches upon this question because I’m not satisfied with this answer